# Other IOS devices ring when my iPhone is called and I cannot turn that off

Tags: ios, continuity

How do I change other iOS devices that ring and receive messages when near my iPhone receiving calls?

Answer (score 4):

On the iPhone - go to Settings and turn off each device you wish to opt out of cals on other devices.

- Settings.app
- Phone
- Calls on Other Devices
- Turn it all off or just toggle the devices you want and don't want individually.

Messages and FaceTime work the same, and are located in settings under Phone.